# Calling a class method from form with no relation to class

Tags: c#, list, class, reference

Sorry for the bad title, my mind is full of confusion and I don't know how best to describe it. Here goes.

I have a class called `FileHandler`. This class reads data from a file and puts it into a List, and it also has a method to write the List back to the file after I've made modifications to it. The class looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/wei5FFpB

Now, the `readDataFile` method of that class is called in my main form (the one that initially loads when you run the program). From there, I open another form called `BranchOverview`. From there, another one can be opened called `EditProduct`. Within this edit product form, I can edit the product details by reference and have it change in the `myArgus` list. What I'm having trouble with is calling the `readDataFile` method in the `FileHandler` class from `EditProduct`.

Since I have no way to reference `myArgus` from `EditProduct`, I can't call the `writeDataFile` method because it accepts `myArgus` as a parameter.

The only way I can think of doing it is having a method in each form class that calls the class below it, all the way down until it gets to my main form where `myArgus` can be passed.

Is there a graceful way to achieve this or have I completely screwed up my entire program in terms of design? If I have, I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction on how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your concern is sharing the instance of `myArgus` between three (or more) forms.

But there are at least few different ways to do it. You can pass this between forms (e.g. as a constructor parameter), you can pass instance of one form to another, you can have a separate class to hold a shared (static) instance of `myArgus`.

There are other minor problems in your code. For example, you don't really have to pass lists by `ref` since you are not changing the reference itself but rather the contents of your lists.

Then, this looks ugly:

```
myArgus.Add(new Branch());
myArgus[branchCounter]._branchID = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
myArgus[branchCounter]._branchName = reader.ReadLine();
...
```

while you really mean:

```
Branch newBranch = new Branch();

newBranch._branchID = ...;
newBranch._branchName = ...;

myArgus.Add( newBranch );
```

Then, when a method is supposed to return the data (`readDataFile`) I think everyone would expect the signature to be:

```
public List<Branch> readDataFile()
```

instead of

```
public void readDataFile(ref List<Branch> myArgus)
```

Comment: A static class seems like a good idea. That way I can make changes to `myArgus` whenever I want in my code and pass it directly to `writeDataFile()` without passing it between classes and making things complicated.

Comment: Correct, if you need a single shared instance of an object, you can safely store it in a static field of a class.

Comment: +1 for recommending removing the `ref` in the method signature, but if the OP is adding multiple files to the same `myArgs` instance, this would require more work on the calling side using `List<myArgs>.AddRange()` to merge multiple data files in to the same list

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Wiktor's answer, your `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` objects should be wrapped in a using statement so they are disposed of properly, even if there is an error.

In your `readDataFile` method:

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataFileLoc))
{

    int branchCounter = 0;
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

In your `writeDataFile` method:

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dataFileLoc))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myArgus.Count; i++)
    {    
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```